# Cant lock screen on xfce

Tags: xfce, lightdm, screen-lock, xscreensaver

A few days before, I wanted to try out xscreensaver as it is knows for its cool screensavers. So I installed that by:

`sudo apt-get install xscreensaver xscreensaver-gl-extra xscreensaver-data-extra`

But after trying it out, I found that this lock screen is not what I expected as it ask for login creds in xscreensaver that looks like this:
[image: xscreensaver login screen]
This looked pretty ugly to me as my default screenlock was better. So I decided to remove xscreensaver from the system. So I ran `sudo apt remove xscreensaver xscreensaver-gl-extra xscreensaver-gl`

But now, when I lock the system using the lock button found on the top right of my desktop, it doesn't lock itself. Thats when I realized I broke something. The lock button works fine if I am logged in as a root user. But doesn't work when I am the user that I always use.

Here's my System Info:

```bsh
$ uname -a
Linux <hostname> 5.10.0-kali9-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.46-1kali1 (2021-06-25) x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ neofetch
<snip>
DE: Xfce 4.16
<snip>
```

Comment: What does `grep LockCommand $HOME/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-session.xml` return?

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov it returns `<property name="LockCommand" type="empty"/>`